# Android - Error while sharing on GooglePlus

Tags: android, google-plus

I have downloaded a sample code from [GooglePlus QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#next_steps) for authentication and [GooglePlus Share](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/interactive-post) for sharing.

Authentication is successful but for sharing it gives an error saying `Can't create the post. Please try again.` How can I get rid of it?

I googled for the same, but couldn't found any solution about it.

Please check the screen shots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you got any reason why this error this error message is showing ?